# phpMailer - Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

I am trying to make a mailing system where by the user can select a specific group of people to send emails. What I am currently facing now is that I couldn't send out emails.

I had tried `$row['email']`, but it will show me error message like

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

I has also tried `$row->$email`, no errors found but no email was to send out.

**NOTE**: I would prefer using Gmail SMTP because I did not have hosting server set up, and I do not have the time to do that anymore. Please kindly advise.

From **doMailingSystem.php**,

```
<?php
include 'dbFunctions.php';
include "mailingSystem.php";

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');

extract($_POST);
$session_id = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($session_id));
$sql = "SELECT student_profile.email FROM student_profile, booking_history WHERE student_profile.student_id = booking_history.student_id and booking_history.booking_date_session LIKE '$session_id%' ";
//print $sql;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = 'usernamer@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->From = 'username@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'X Team';
    $mail->AddAddress($row['email']);

    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
    $mail->Body = $_POST['message'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
<?php
// echo $statusMessage;
?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be using `->property` for types of `StdClass`. `['index']` is for arrays.

Comment: Oh man: `extract($_POST);`. Words can't describe how bad an idea that is.

Comment: You really should try [starting with sane code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) rather than sticking random bits together and hoping it works.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to send you message:

```
...
$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->Body = $_POST['message'];
$mail->send();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Here
```

And you might want to check that the e-mail address is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Hi @jeroen, thank you for your help! I must have left that out when I copied and pasted from another file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_object()` in your `while` statement. Then you can use it as `array` like `$row['email'];`